# How to relate these tables in an ER Diagram?

Tags: sql, relational-database, entity, erd

I know this is a common issue, I am just very rusty and do not remember how to correctly model this diagram.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy3zN.png

Each `Order` contains multiple `[LineItem]` and multiple `[Designs]`

However, each for each `[LineItem]` I'd like to associate 1 or more of the available `[Designs]` in the order.

How can this be done?

Obviously, I cannot simply create a relationship between `[LineItem]` and `[Designs]`, correct?

I thought of moving the relationship as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDoWR.png

However, then I face the problem of `[Designs]` no longer being associated with an `[Order]`.

Comment: Each LineItem must be associated with 1 or more Designs in the same order. How many LineItems can each Design be associated with?

Comment: Each design can be associated with 1 or more LineItems. Its a many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

Your diagrams are not ER diagrams. To be called an ER diagram, the diagramming notation must be capable of representing ER concepts like entity sets (tables represent entity relations), ternary and higher-order relationships, attributes on relationships and relationships on relationships. What you have are table diagrams, representing physical models.

Here is an ER diagram (conceptual model) showing a many-to-many relationship between `LineItems` and `Designs`. For simplicity I left out non-key attributes.

[image: Designs and LineItems ER diagram]

I also translated this into a physical model. However, there is a risk of inconsistency if `LineItem_Designs` is implemented as in your 2nd example. The DBMS is unable to ensure that only `LineItems` and `Designs` from the same order are associated with each other. To counter this, we can use controlled redundancy.

[image: Designs and LineItems table diagram]

By adding `OrderID` to the `LineItems_Designs` table, we can use overlapping composite FK constraints to ensure consistency. `(DesignID, OrderID)` in `LineItems_Designs` will reference the same two fields in `Designs`, and `(LineID, OrderID)` in `LineItems_Designs` will reference the same two fields in `LineItems`.

Here is a simplified SQL script to illustrate:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
  CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
  Customer_Name VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  Company_Name VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  Phone_Number VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  Email VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders (
  OrderID INT NOT NULL,
  CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
  Order_Title VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  Order_Date DATE NULL,
  Due_Date DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers (CustomerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Designs (
  DesignID INT NOT NULL,
  OrderID INT NOT NULL,
  Design_Type VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  Design_Location VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  Design_Colors VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (DesignID),
  UNIQUE KEY Design_Order (DesignID, OrderID),
  FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES Orders (OrderID)
);

CREATE TABLE LineItems (
  LineID INT NOT NULL,
  OrderID INT NOT NULL,
  Product_Description VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  Product_Color VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (LineID),
  UNIQUE KEY LineItem_Order (LineID, OrderID),
  FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES Orders (OrderID)
);

CREATE TABLE LineItems_Designs (
  DesignID INT NOT NULL,
  LineID INT NOT NULL,
  OrderID INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (DesignID, OrderID) REFERENCES Designs (DesignID, OrderID)
  FOREIGN KEY (LineID, OrderID) REFERENCES LineItems (LineID, OrderID)
);
```

Note the composite unique keys in `Designs` and `LineItems` to support the FK constraints.

Finally, a note about your terminology / concepts. Despite tagging your question with `erd` and `relational-database`, your language reminds me of the network data model. In the ER model, relationships don't map to foreign key constraints. In Chen's method, relationship relations map to their own tables. If we allow for denormalization of one-to-many binary relationship relations into the entity relations of the entity sets on the many side, we can say that relationships map to sets of columns in a table. For example, the relationship between `LineItem` and `Order` is represented by the pair `(LineID PK, OrderID)` (whether in its own table or not). Foreign key constraints are only integrity constraints, and don't relate tables (observe that SELECT queries are unaffected by their removal). In the relational model, tables represent relations, not the elements being related. The elements being related are values and domains, which represent entities and entity sets, respectively.